# Programmatically convert SVG shapes to paths (lineto, moveto)

Tags: svg, automation, coordinates, shapes, save-as

I have an SVG file coming from Inkscape, Illustrator, or any other application. I want to convert the shapes to `lineto`, `moveto`, `curveto` format.

What I want is something like:

```
./Appname svgfile outfilewithpath
```

I will give the SVG file as an argument, then my application will convert the object into the respective paths.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to convert elements such as `rect`, `circle`, `ellipse` and `polygon` into paths?

Comment: I come to know about Inkscape and found that it can do the Job, but what I want is I have ready made svg from any software and wanted to convert object into path. i.e. Move to Line To. Qt, Perl, Python, C, C++ any solution are accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Inkscape has a command-line interface. Use the [Inkscape man page](http://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html) along with the [verb source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/view/head:/src/verbs.cpp) for reference:

The `ObjectToPath` verb converts an object to a path:

```
inkscape filename.svg --select=myobject --verb=ObjectToPath --export-plain-svg=filename_to_path.svg
```

The `export-text-to-path` argument converts text nodes to paths:

```
inkscape filename.svg --export-eps=filename.eps --export-text-to-path
```

These are related questions on how to run InkScape from Perl, Ruby, PHP or Python:

- [Using the Inkscape shell from perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695641/1113772)
- [Run inkscape in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219507/1113772)
- [Calling Inkscape in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651826/1113772)
- [Inkscape Merge Ruby Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/inkscape_merge/versions/0.1.3)

Comment: Inkscape itself can do the stuff and I am also very well aware about inkscape command line. I am looking for some other solution, perhaps Python or perl. for ex. Python/PerlApp svgfile outfilewithcoordinate.txt. I know svg is xml file and can be parsed with xml library.

Answer (score 5):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
inkscape -f filename.svg --verb EditSelectAll --verb SelectionUnGroup --verb EditSelectAll --verb ObjectToPath --verb FileSave --verb FileQuit
```

It takes about 9 seconds to run and briefly opens the inkscape gui, which becomes the active application, so it's not ideal, but it's the only answer I could find that actually works.