# Convert all kinds of shapes in svg to path

Tags: javascript, svg

I want a converter for svg file which will convert all kinds of shapes for me to path. For instance if I have the following svg:

```html
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
  <rect width="100" height="100" x="100" y="0"/>
</svg>
```

I want this code to be converted to this:

```html
<svg height="1000" width="1000">
  <path d="M0,50a50,50 0 1,0 100,0a50,50 0 1,0-100,0"/>
  <path d="M100,0L200,0 200,100 100,100z"/>
</svg>
```

Is there any online converter for this? Or is there any way to achieve this using javascript . or can I do this with Adobe Illustrator? if yes I would be very grateful to know how.

Comment: https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/element-to-path

Comment: do you know any online converter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG - Convert all shapes/primitives to <path>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31575550/svg-convert-all-shapes-primitives-to-path)