# Need to create a PDF with graphs using Google Charts

Tags: php, laravel, charts

I'm having some troubles to solve a problem.

I need to create a PDF file with some graphs, this graphs should not be showed to the user.

Since google charts needs to be rendered, what's the best way to achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create graphs with PHP and export to PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581738/create-graphs-with-php-and-export-to-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating a PDF for the user to download, or generating PDF reports in the background, there are some PHP charting library that can generate charts as PDF directly, such as [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com).